# storing user_id in session variable

Tags: php, mysql

so I have this site where drivers can login and register.

at the moment i can store the username in a session variable, im trying to do the same for the user_id so the user can later retrieve it when adding more details for a job.
heres what I got so far:

```
function selectUser($conn, $username, $password, $userID)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = :username"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
 //$stmt->bindValue(':user_ID', $userID);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {

        if (md5($password) == $row->password) {  
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['user_ID'] = $userID;
   //       $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as " . $username; 
            return true;
        }



        return false; 
    }
    else
    {
        //echo "Your details were not found";
        return false;
    }
}
```

when the driver accesses another page:

```
<?php
     if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
}   

require_once ("config.inc.php");

try
    {
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DATA_SOURCE, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    }

catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
    echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
    }

if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
    echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as <b>".$_SESSION['username']."</b> <img class='clientView' src='images/loginIcon.png' alt='client'>"; }
    else { 
    echo "You are currently not logged in";
    }


    $login = $_SESSION['user_ID'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_ID = :login"; 

$term = $conn->prepare($query);
$term->bindValue(':login', $login);
$term->execute();

$login = $term->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    print_r($_SESSION); 
    ?>
```

tested it using print r and for some reason it doesnt seem to be collecting the user_ID.

am i doing something wrong?

upon test: https://snag.gy/6bGd5m.jpg

when calling the function:

```
$username=trim($_POST['username']);
$password=$_POST['password'];

$username= htmlspecialchars($username);
$validForm = true;

if (empty($_POST["username"]))
            {
            $validForm=false;
            }
if (empty($_POST["password"]))  
            {
            $validForm=false;
            }
if (!$validForm) {

$error = "please ensure all fields are filled in";
include("add.php");
return false;

}           


$conn=getConn();
$successLogin=selectUser($conn,$username,$password);
if($successLogin)
{

       header( 'Location: profile.php');
}else{
       $error = "The details you have entered are incorrect";
      include("add.php"); 
}
```

Comment: you don't plan on using MD5 live do you? use password_hash() / password_verify() if you value your work and your userbase

Comment: so tell us; did you start the session and doe the session arrays all contain value?

Comment: Are you *supplying* a `$userID` value?  How have you confirmed that?  Where are you testing it?

Comment: dont worry, md5 is just temporary. I did start the session and only the username is brought back. the user_id seems to be empty. bear in mind its also a primary key.

Comment: check for errors then and var_dump

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you sure the variable is filled? (Try your best not to ignore people's comments, such as @David's). Show the code and try debugging to see if the content is there.

Comment: so the user goes to a html page, it already has the session start ready and I call it with this: $login = $_SESSION['user_ID'];

Comment: so.... what's the problem then? you have your array showing up, so I don't think you're showing us the code we should be seeing, being the one(s) after they logged in.

Comment: @JamesGreen: As for the problem itself... Where do you ever set a value for `$userID`?  Where do you read back that session value?

Comment: `echo "Welcome, you are now logged in as " . $username; echo " and your USER ID is: " . $userID;` - *n'est-ce pas?*

Comment: well I don't see you starting the session in the other file you now just shown us.

Comment: Also, you _still_ haven't said how you are calling the `selectUser()` function and how you're passing the values (which was asked in the beginning). I'm out...

Comment: @JamesGreen: You keep editing the code in the question to reflect suggestions given... Have you checked if any of those suggestions have actually altered the results?  The code is a moving target, it keeps changing.  What is the *actual code* which demonstrates the problem?  Additionally, in all of your edits, you still haven't shown where you confirm that you actually *set a value* to that session variable.  If you're not *setting a value* then it stands to reason that you can't *read that value*.

Comment: please show us $userID immediately inside the function. maybe $userID is empty. is unusual to call this function with all known values as parameters. Why should you query the database if you already have all values?? I suspect you should have something like $_SESSION['user_ID'] = row["user_ID"];

Comment: when the user registers, the user id is inserted into the database as null value because its automatically generated being the primary key, so when the user logins, I wanted to use the session variable to retrieve the user id for another page

Comment: @David ive tried the suggestions but no luck, the reason im trying to avoid adding any code that has nothing to do with this is so I can avoid putting any confusion in terms of what im trying to do

Comment: @JamesGreen: *"code that has nothing to do with this"* - I would think that the code which sets the value you're looking for would have *everything* to do with this.  Nowhere in the code provided do you ever *call your function*.  So, if this is all of the relevant code, then the problem seems obvious... You never call the `selectUser` function.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, let me add the code which calls the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug.

Where do you store the value in the session state?:

```
$_SESSION['user_ID'] = $userID;
```

Ok, so where does `$userID` come from?:

```
function selectUser($conn, $username, $password, $userID)
{
    //...
```

Ok, so where does the function parameter come from?:

```
selectUser($conn,$username,$password)
```

Nowhere.  You never supplied a value to be stored in session, so no value was stored in session.

It seems unlikely that you actually want to *supply* the User ID to the function.  Instead, you *probably* want to supply just the username and password as you currently do and then get the User ID from the database.  Which might look more like this:

```
$_SESSION['user_ID'] = $row["user_ID"];
```

Or perhaps:

```
$_SESSION['user_ID'] = $row->user_id;
```

Or however you get values from your `$row` object.

But basically the important lesson here is... When a value isn't what you expect it to be, trace back where that value came from.  Chances are you have a false assumption somewhere.

Comment: Yeah it looks like your right, apologies for that. I guess its the way I worded it. Ill be honest but im more of a front end guy than backend, which is why I caused soo much unnecessary confusion.

Comment: @JamesGreen: I honestly don't have any links for that.  If it were me I'd just Google for them.  There is, of course, a lot of crap out there.  It's just going to take experience and trial-and-error to practice and learn.  The debugging and critical thinking skills are more important than the syntax and tools demonstrated by tutorials.  Or, to put it another way, debugging is a more important skill than actual coding.  Any tutorial, good or bad, will give you coding practice.